# Best way to pair off all users in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I currently have a DB with a large group of users, and am looking for a way to pair them all up, based on a certain number of things.

What is the best way to randomly iterate through the db of users, and pair them all up with each other? Ensuring that nobody misses out, and that time you do so everything is randomized.

Has anyone had any experience with this before?  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are probably lots of ways to do this, but if the database can handle a random query you could grab all the users like this (where RANDOM() is your DB's random function)

```
User.order('RANDOM()').in_groups_of(2) do |a,b|
  # code to match user a to user b
end
```

You'd have to deal with an odd number of users and the above isn't efficient, but it will work.